# How to replace all occurrences of an object key in an array? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

So I have an array, containing objects like this:

```
var items_array = {
 value: 5555,
 shipping: 444,
 transaction_id: 12345678,
  items: [
  {
  id: "1234",
  title: "testitem1",
  unitPrice: 12,
  quantity: 1
  },
  {
  id: "4321",
  title: "testitem2",
  unitPrice: 21,
  quantity: 2
 }]};
```

Now I want to replace the "id" with "item_id", "unitPrice" with "price" and the title with "item_name" in each object in the array. Sadly, I cannot convert the array into a string, so the .replace method doesn't work here and as far as I know, the .map method only allows me to replace the properties, not the keys themselves. Also, this array can have one or multiple items inside it, so the solution has to work wheter I have 1 item or 50. Also, I can't use "=>" as this is an old javascript enviroment below 1.7 with no support for "modern" solutions like this.

Do you guys have any idea how to do this? I am fairly new to Javascript sadly and my Google skills turned out to be insufficent in this matter. If you need further explaination, please just ask and I will answer to the best of my abilities.

Comment: There are a number of different ways to do it, however StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.  You need to share what you have tried already and explain where you're having issues.

Comment: .map() is the simplest way to do this. Changing keys is simple, you just [write a callback that returns the new object](https://jsfiddle.net/usw8zvej/) from the given data. Also, given that `items_array` is an object, are we just talking about `items_array.items` which is an array?

Comment: @Tibrogargan I am not asking for a complete code. I need a method which I can use to develop my own. If you are telling me that .map or Array.map would work for me in this case, I will look into these further and try to figure it out by myself. I have tried .replace so far but as I explained it before, that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you. Yes, I made the problem here a little simpler, but the example I have here is inside another array already. It's not my code and can't change it, so this is all I have to work with.

Comment: Just as an aside: string manipulation is always a last resort when it comes to data manipulation. It's the unsafest and ugliest way, and will quickly lead to a huge mess if the data is in any way not as expected. Never use that if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look on [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Here I use `items` for example.

### Old browser

```js
var items = [{
  id: "1234",
  title: "testitem1",
  unitPrice: 12,
  quantity: 1
}, {
  id: "4321",
  title: "testitem2",
  unitPrice: 21,
  quantity: 2
}];

var newItems = items.map(function (item) {
  item.item_id = item.id;
  delete item.id;
  item.price = item.unitPrice;
  delete item.unitPrice;
  item.item_name = item.title;
  delete item.title;
  return item;
});

console.log(newItems);
```

### Modern way

```js
let items = [
   {
    id: "1234",
    title: "testitem1",
    unitPrice: 12,
    quantity: 1
   },
   {
    id: "4321",
    title: "testitem2",
    unitPrice: 21,
    quantity: 2
   }
]

const newItems = items.map((item) => {
  item.item_id = item.id
  delete item.id

  item.price = item.unitPrice
  delete item.unitPrice

  item.item_name = item.title
  delete item.title

  return item
})

console.log(newItems)
```

Comment: @amlozek I have update an old browser version, please take a look

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough rep to upvote your solution, but I can't express enough how thankful I am for your solution. The old method worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Never mind, happy to know that I can help. You can also check out `Array.reduce`, in case there are complex situation in the future.